# How can i create a variable inside of while loop

Tags: php, mysql

here is my php codes-

```
<?php    
$dbhost = 'localhost';    
$dbuser = 'root';    
$dbpass = '';      
$dbname = 'moviefone';    

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);  

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{  
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();    
}
$query = (isset($_GET['search-text']) ? strip_tags($_GET['search-text']) : '');

$num_result = 0;

$min_length = 3;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

$query = htmlspecialchars($query);             
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%')")    or die(mysql_error());               

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){   
    while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results)){
    $title=$results['title'];
    $images=$results['images'];
            $num_results++;
echo '<div id="search_result">
<a href=""><img src="'.$images.'" width="77px" height="111px" alt="" /></a>
<a href="" >'.$title.'</a>
<br />
<br />
</div>
<div id="b-1" class="clearfix"></div>
</div>';



    }

}
else{
    echo "No results";
}

}
else{ 
echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}

?>
```

when i echo $num_result within the while loop it display perfectly.but when i try to echo it out side of the loop showing undefined variable.i have tried setting the variable as global scope.but it was still showing undefined variable : $num_result on line 72.

`<div id="page-header">
     <h1>Search Result for 
     <span class="query-text"> 
     "<?php echo $_GET['search-text']; ?>"</span></h1></div>
     <div id="b-1" class="clearfix"></div>
     <div class="query-result"><h2>Movies<span class="num_result">
     (<?php echo   "$num_result\n";?>)</span></h2>
     </div>`     - This where i want to echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply after a total count for all results? If so, you need to set your variable to zero before the loop. Your code is currently overwriting that variable each loop.

```
$num_result = 0;
```

... and in your case, each loop is only going to contain **one** record, so there is no need to use the `+=` [assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) here. The value will always be one, so you can just increment your counter by one like this:

```
$num_result++;
```

... then at the end, your output code should work nicely. As long as you set `$num_result` to zero high enough up in your code (e.g. outside that if statement), you won't get an undefined error. I would say this is happening at the moment because your if statement is not evaluating to true (you don't have any query results) thus your variable isn't getting defined.

> EDIT

I'm going to give you a broken down example of how this should work:

```
<?php

$num_result = 0;
$query = // your query here

while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $num_result++;
    // output your table info here
}

echo 'Total results: ' . $num_result;

?>
```

> EDIT

Looking at your PasteBin output, your problem is pretty clear - you're trying to echo `$num_result` before it's been defined. The problem you're facing is that are outputting a variable which is being processed during a loop over your database results, but you want to output that variable before you've done the loop. Try this instead:

> Put your database query code at the **top** of your page:

```
<?php    
$dbhost = 'localhost';    
$dbuser = 'root';    
$dbpass = '';      
$dbname = 'moviefone';    

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);  

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$num_results = 0;

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{  
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();    
}
$query = (isset($_GET['search-text']) ? strip_tags($_GET['search-text']) : '');

$min_length = 3;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){

$query = htmlspecialchars($query);            
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%')")    or die(mysql_error());
```

> Then use mysql_num_rows() to output your total instead of relying on `$num_result`

```
<div class="query-result">
    <h2>Movies<span class="num_result">(<?php echo mysql_num_rows($raw_results)?>)</span?></h2>
</div>
```

... and I cringed having to write `mysql_fetch_assoc` - mysql functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead. [Here's a tutorial to get you started with PDO.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/214733-introduction-to-pdo/) I see you're using a mysqli function or two in your code already, which is fairly confusing, but good on you - convert the rest too!

Comment: when i `echo "num_result\n"` inside of the while loop it display fine.but when i try to echo it out side of the loop it shows undefined variable.ex-`<span>movies(<?php echo "num_result\n" ?></span>` then only it shows undefined variable :num_result.By the way i have tried your solution still getting the error.

Comment: I'm going to go and assume that you **are** adding the required `$` in front of `num_result` in your example...

Comment: Just for clarity, can you please update your code to show that.

Comment: i have tried before what and also tried it now what you just said.but still  `Notice: Undefined variable: num_result in C:\wamp\www\test\website3\search.php on line 72`.

Comment: @akash ok mate, enough pissing around. Post your entire code, because the errors and output you say you want is not in the code you've provided.

Comment: @akash, and remove this line `$num_result = count($results['id']);` - don't use it in tandem with my example, that defeats the purpose.

Comment: i have done it and edited the code as your example.is it ok now ?

Comment: No, put your output code into your main code block as it would be in your script. There's clearly some inconsistency between what you're posting here and what's actually in your code, so just copy and paste all your code into your post or use PasteBin and post the link to it: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @akash - answer updated, in future please post your complete code when you ask the question, it would have saved both of us a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

when you define variable in while clause variable life time finish when you exit while loop( you don't have variable outside of while )
so if you want to use variable outside while but change it in while => define variable before while clause.